# I can't find any option to change a sound theme

Tags: 14.04, unity, sound, customization

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity (dual boot, but separate hard drives).

I have looked all over the settings for a way to change the sound theme, but I can't find one. There is one spot in the settings where you can choose an alert sound, but that doesn't look like it would be what I want and it only gives the option of default. I have the Unity Tweak Tool, but there are no sound options present there. I downloaded a theme and placed the theme folder in `/usr/share/sounds`, but I don't know where to choose the theme